# strtok doesn't split the string properly

Tags: c, string, strtok

When I pass "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin" into my function, when I print each token, I only get 3 outputs (instead of 5). I don't see any issues after checking it 100 times. But everytime it only prints 3 outputs.

/usr/bin

/bin

/u/usr/bin

(null)

```
char** tokenised(char* directories) {
    char** directoryArray = malloc(1000*sizeof(char*));
    char *token;
    int i = 0;

     //First token
     token = strtok(directories, ":");

     while(token != NULL) 
     {
         directoryArray[i] = strdup(token);
         token = strtok(NULL, ":");
         i++;
     }

     int j = 0; 
     while(directoryArray[j] != NULL) {
          printf("%s\n", directoryArray[j]);
          j++;
     }
     return directoryArray;
}
```

The function that calls tokenised, it has problems

```
  int searchForFile(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     char* fileName = argv[0];
     char* pathBuffer = malloc(sizeof(PATH)+1);
     strcpy(pathBuffer, PATH);

     int i = 0;
     printf("%s\n", PATH);

     char** directoryArray = tokenised(pathBuffer);
     printf("%s\n", directoryArray[4]);

     while(directoryArray[i] != NULL) {
         printf("%i\n", i);
         printf("Searching directory: '%s'\n", directoryArray[i]);
         //Form an address out 2 strings
              char *address =   malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(directoryArray[i])+sizeof(char)*strlen(fileName)+1*sizeof(char));
          strcpy(address, directoryArray[i]);
          strcat(address, "/");
          strcat(address, fileName);
          argv[0] = address;
          if(execute(argc, argv) == 0) {
              return 0;
          }
    i++;
  }
  printf("Search for file: '%s' failed.", fileName);
  return 1;
  }
```

Comment: It prints five words for me [demo](http://ideone.com/uHaGpx). One thing that's definitely wrong in your code is that you stop printing when you encounter `NULL`. However, parts of `directoryArray` beyond index `i` are not initialized. See my demo on how to work around this. If you want a fix, add `directoryArray[i] = NULL` after the first loop. However, the problem could lead to printing more data, not less.

Comment: Show the caller to function `tokenised()`

Comment: Path is     
p  = getenv("PATH");
PATH = strdup(p == NULL ? DEFAULT_PATH : p);  check_allocation(PATH); 'code'

Comment: which pretty much outputs the string "usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin". @dasblinkenlight when I executed it as a seperate file, it worked correctly. However when I changed the 'while' loop to 'for' loop in my file the output is the same, despite having pretty much the same code. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you make `pathBuffer`. According to your comments, `PATH` is a pointer. Therefore, the call

```
char* pathBuffer = malloc(sizeof(PATH)+1);
strcpy(pathBuffer, PATH);
```

allocates memory for a pointer plus one byte, not for the content of the `PATH` pointer. Copying the long input string into this short buffer leads to undefined behavior. Most likely, the memory of the string's tail is shared with some other data structure, leading to truncation of the string before `strtok` starts working on it. You can confirm this by printing the `directories` string at the beginning of `tokenised()` function.

Since you are using `strdup` in other places, changing the above lines to

```
char* pathBuffer = strdup(PATH);
```

will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After this loop

```
 while(token != NULL) 
 {
     directoryArray[i] = strdup(token);
     token = strtok(NULL, ":");
     i++;
 }
```

write

```
directoryArray[i] = NULL;
```

or

```
directoryArray[i] = token;
```

In this case the following loop will be correct

```
 int j = 0; 
 while(directoryArray[j] != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", directoryArray[j]);
      j++;
 }
```

**Edit:** After you appended your code example then this statement

```
char *address =   malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(directoryArray[i])+sizeof(char)*strlen(fileName)+1*sizeof(char));
```

must be changed to

```
char *address =   malloc( strlen(directoryArray[i])+strlen(fileName)+2);
                                                                     ^^^
```

because you also append a slash to the string

```
strcat(address, "/");
```

Comment: This will fix printing too much, but it looks like OP's problem is printing too little.

Comment: Yep, I changed it today for some reason, when that part was correct before. However it doesn't solve the problem, after the 2 tokens, the 3rd token is wrong, and the remaining 2 aren't stored. :S

Comment: @caha11 What is execute and what does it do? I think the problem is somewhere else apart the code you showed.

Comment: @caha11 Yes ,its not the problem with `strtok` but with your string .